# android - how to write a video player

Tags: android

I've written a very simple video player , this is the code:

```
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.20/test/v_2.flv");        
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();
```

layout:

```
 <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="161dp" />
```

It play the video but how can I add these features to it ?

1- a loading comes on the player while it downloading the video

2- it has play , stop and moving back or forward bar when I click on it .

How can I do so ?

Comment: While downloading a video, are you using AsyncTask? If yes, start a loader in its `onPreExecute` ,finish it in `onPostExecute` and download the video in `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.20/test/v_2.flv"); 

//SHOW THE PROGRESS DIALOG(LOADING...)
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();

try{      
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController); //ADD MEDIA CONTROLS(PLAY, STOP, FORWARD etc.) 
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

videoView.requestFocus();

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    videoView.start();
}
});
```

Comment: thanks , it works nice . Just a small question , is  there anyway I make the controllers smaller ?

Comment: @max59, beside providing a working solution, please add some details about what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: @mahdi you can create a custom `MediaController` to make the buttons small. Take a look at [this](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller) link.

Comment: @sufiyan There was no problem to begin with, so I didn't fix anything. I just answered the question, and I think you haven't read my answer completely as I've added the comments right next to the code that explain everything.

Comment: "There was no problem to begin with" -- then you should have mentioned that there was no problem in the OP code.

Comment: OP didn't ask if anything was wrong with his code. So why should I mention that there was a problem in the code?